# return statement vs no return statement?

Tags: python, return

```
def nat_fn1(k):
  if k == 0:
    return 1
  elif k%2 == 0:
    return 2
  else:
    return nat_fn1 (k-1)
```

I first tried `nat_fn1(5)` and I got an answer of 2. This was expected. Then I tried the same code without return, I got a value of None, this was expected too. So applying the same concept, I tried this code :

```
def process_strings(s,t):
   if s == "":
      if not(t== ""):
         print(t)
   else:
      print("{0}{1}".format(s[0],t[0]))
      process_strings(s[1:], t[1:])
```

I tried `process_strings("cat","dog")`, expecting None as there is no return in the recursion. However, I still got an answer of :

```
cd
ao
tg
```

I understand how it got these values. But there's no return statement. Why is this working?

Comment: The function **did** return None

Comment: Your just printing values, the function isn't returning them.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Sorry I'm new to Python. So what's happening when I do recursive without return? Does it still recurse or stop before recursing?

Comment: The function runs regardless of its return value (even None). That means that the printing is executed and the line calling the same function is also executed.

Comment: Zondo, using the same logic, I tried nat_fn1 (5) to the first program without the return. so this program recurses, can runs again as nat_fn1(4),  thus 4 % 2 == 0 should return 2. However, it doesnt. Why?

Comment: Each function will be called. The one that results in 1 or 2 will not do anything with that information (I.e. no return) so you won't *see* the result, but it is calculated. You can verify that by printing it ;)

Comment: Here's a tip. `print(process_strings("cat","dog"))`... That does print None as well as the other output. Meanwhile, `print(nat_fn1(5))` only outputs 2. You say you "apply the same concept", but you really didn't because your other function doesn't properly return anything. It's also unclear if you are wanting to return a list or a string

Answer (score 1):

What you get is not the return value, but the output of `print` statement.
If you *run your code interactively in interactive prompt, it will echo the `return` value*.

But if you run it in a file, it won't do that automatically. If you don't print the return value exactly, it will ignore the return value and output nothing.

Comment: I know that but why is this program recursing to begin with without the return statement? To be getting 3 different printed outputs, format(s[0],t[0]) , s and t has to be different each time, proving that this program recurses. So i tried nat_fn2(5) to the first piece of code i posted without the return statement. I was expecting an answer of 2 since this program recurses and the elif statement with k % 2  has a return statement. Yet I got nothing returned. I'm completely lost right now

Comment: `process_strings(s[1:], t[1:])` is recursive. Though it doesn't return value, it does some work. That is, it prints the string. So it recursively prints strings. @Compsci

Comment: is there any way I can chat with you? I'm still a bit confused at this point

Comment: chat in the chat room, you can create one @Compsci

Comment: How would I access this chat room?

Comment: @compsci: That requires 20 reputation. You'll need something external.

Comment: would this work with you? https://discordapp.com/

Comment: @Compsci, How can I contact with you in that?

Comment: @zhenguoli , "open discord", it creates an account for you automatically, bottom left will be a user code, I can add you, not personal info needed to sign up

Comment: Oh, my username is zhenguoli @Compsci.

Comment: could i get the 4 digit code , @zhenguoli

Comment: @Compsci, 6409.

Comment: @zhenguoli with those exact capitalizations?

Comment: @Compsci, yes, it is.

Comment: I'm trying to add you right now, for some reason it's causing troubles. Could you try adding helao #0221

Comment: hey, i found a better alternative. This works. http://www.disposablechat.com/

Comment: room : cshelpplz

Comment: @Compsci, I'm combing back.